# How can I calculate the J value in an antiferromagnetic material?

Tags: density-functional-theory, magnetism, condensed-matter, model-hamiltonians, spin-exchange

I am new to DFT, especially in doing DFT for magnetic materials. I recently came across this [paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.1999631#header) which indicated the calculation of the J value in the case of antiferromagentic materials as per the formula.

$$E_{HS}- E_{BS} = -J(2S_{1}S_{2}-S_{2}) $$

The paper describes the terms as  follows:

> $E_{HS}$ : Energy of the triple state {High Spin}: I have calculated
> this by constrained magnetization method in Quantum ESPRESSO.
>
> $E_{BS}$ : Energy of the Broken symmetry state {Low spin}: I have
> doubts regarding what this is; I do believe its the anti-ferromagnetic
> state {total magnetization = zero}. **Correct me if Im wrong!**
>
> The $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ in the paper : where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the
> total spins of the paramagnetic centers and $S_1$>$S_2$ has been
> assumed for heterodinuclear complexes using the Heisenberg
> Hamiltonian. **I didnt quite understand this : How can I calculate
> this?**

Thank you in Advance!!

Comment: +1. Here's some related questions: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1548/5, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1618/5, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1678/5

Answer (score 4):

In the attached paper they have used the broken symmetry method to calculate the exchange.

Assuming that you're dealing with a 1D chain of spins. you can do this using quantum ESPRESSO via the following steps:

1. Create a 2x1x1 [super cell from your CIF file using VESTA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnbKn4QZdl8) (assuming that your 1d chain is along the first basis vector)
2. For the [SCF calculation using QE,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Lcd0QD_Z7s) you need to consider two cases a ferromagnetic state and an antiferromagnetic state. Here the magnetic moment on the atom (one in each unit cell) should be constrained as follows in the &SYSTEM name card:

For the AFM case:

```
  starting_magnetization(1) = 1.0
  starting_magnetization(2) = -1.0
  constrained_magnetization = 'atomic'
```

For the FM case:

```
  starting_magnetization(1) = 1.0
  starting_magnetization(2) = 1.0
  constrained_magnetization = 'atomic'
```

3. The difference in energy should give you the J value:

   $$ J = E_{FM}-E_{AFM}\tag{1}$$

I hope this is correct!

Comment: +1 the one minor edit I made was only so that if anyone needs to refer to that equation they can say "as seen in Eq. 1 of [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4998/5)" rather than "as seen in *the equation* in [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4998/5)".